# putting functions that read user input files into and loop using exceptions

Tags: python

The program is reading a file of keywords with number values attached to them. Then it is reading a file of a couple thousand tweets containing the latitude and longitude and the text of the tweet. You have to sort the tweets into specific regions and then calculate a sentiment average for each region based on the keywords and values of the first document. The user has to input these to two files and it has to have a try statement with exception errors. The functions work alone to calculate the proper values but when i go to put it in the try statement i get these errors:

Traceback (most recent call last):for line 129 main() and line 16 sortKets(keys). And last error line 56 keyword[lines[0]] = int(lines[1]) IndexError: list index out of range
  is there anything i can do to fix it?

List item

```
eastern = []
central = []
mountain = []
pacific = []
keyword = {}
easternsum =[]
centralsum= []
mountainsum = []
pacificsum = []
    def main() :
    done = False
    while not done:
        try:
            keys = input("Enter file: ")
            readkeys(keys)
            sortKeys(keys)

            tweets = input("Enter second file: ")
            readtweets(tweets)
            sorttweet(tweets)


            calcsentiment()
            print("The eastern amount of tweets is",len(easternsum))
            print("The eastern happiness score              is",sum(easternsum)/len(easternsum))
            print("The central amount of tweets is",len(centralsum))
        print("The central happiness score    is",sum(centralsum)/len(centralsum))
        print("The mountain amount of tweets is",len(mountainsum))
        print("The mountain happiness score is",sum(mountainsum)/len(mountainsum))
        print("The pacific amount of tweets is",len(pacificsum))
        print("The pacific happiness score is",sum(pacificsum)/len(pacificsum))
        done = True

    except IOError:
        print("Error, file not found.")

    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid file.")

    except RuntimeError as error:
        print("Error", str(error))



def readkeys(keys):
    keys = open(keys, "r")

def readtweets(tweets):
    tweets = open(tweets, "r")



def sortKeys(keys):
    for line in keys :
       lines = line.split(",")
       keyword[lines[0]] = int(lines[1])

def sorttweet(tweets) :
    for line in tweets :
        stuff = line.split(" ",5)
        long = float(stuff[0].strip("[,"))
        lat = float(stuff[1].strip('],'))
        tweet = stuff[5]
        if 24.660845 < long < 49.189787 and -87.518395 < lat < -67.444574 :
            eastern.append(tweet)
        if 24.660845 < long < 49.189787 and -101.998892 < lat < -87.518395 :
            central.append(tweet)
        if 24.660845 < long < 49.189787 and -115.236428 < lat < -101.998892 :
            mountain.append(tweet)
        if 24.660845 < long < 49.189787 and -125.242264 < lat < -115.236428 :
            pacific.append(tweet)




def calcsentiment():
    for tweet in eastern :
        tweetlist = tweet.split()
        count = 0
        tweetV = 0
        for word in tweetlist:
            if word in keyword :
                count = count + 1
                tweetV = tweetV + keyword[word]
        if count > 0:
            easternsum.append(tweetV / count)

for tweet in central:
    tweetlist2 = tweet.split()
    count = 0
    tweetV = 0
    for word in tweetlist2 :
        if word in keyword :
            count = count + 1
            tweetV = tweetV + keyword[word]
    if count > 0:
        centralsum.append(tweetV / count)


for tweet in mountain:
    tweetlist3 = tweet.split()
    count = 0
    tweetV = 0
    for word in tweetlist3 :
        if word in keyword :
            count = count + 1
            tweetV = tweetV + keyword[word]
    if count > 0:
        mountainsum.append(tweetV / count)

for tweet in pacific:
    tweetlist4 = tweet.split()
    count = 0
    tweetV = 0
    for word in tweetlist4 :
        if word in keyword :
            count = count + 1
            tweetV = tweetV + keyword[word]
    if count > 0:
        pacificsum.append(tweetV / count)
calcsentiment()







main()
```

Comment: I think *you* have to sort the tweets.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem here:

```
def sortKeys(keys): 
    for line in keys : 
        lines = line.split(",") 
        keyword[lines[0]] = int(lines[1])
```

when you split the line, you don't get 2 tokens, just one.
That happens when the line you are trying to split does not contain a ',' character. 
Try in python console something line "xxxx".split(",") and you will see the result is ["xxxx"], so a list with just one element, while in your code lines[1] tries to access the second element of a list.